# Bootstrap carousel isnt working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

The carousel-slider of bootstrap is not working.

Can someone point out the mistake?

```
The jsfiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/tech_boy/rofrjp6n/
```

Comment: "Is not working" is a vague description of your problem. What exactly doesn't work?! Please post some code.

Comment: 1. Please read the bootstrap docs, try something before just through a question.
2. jsfiddle is really nice, but, please let us know what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jsfiddle doesn't include

1. jQuery and
2. bootstrap.js.

Therefore the carousel is only there in CSS, but without any functionality.

And, not entirely necessary, you can add

```
$('.carousel').carousel();
```

to your javascript to start the carousel manually.